# CSLA CLASSES with C#.net and using of csla clases in different cases

Tags: csla

how to code validations for a textbox fields using csla classes,please explain clearly with one example and using of csla classes in different cases..

Answer (score 2):

The use of business, validation, and authorization rules is covered pretty thoroughly in the [Using CSLA 4: Creating Business Objects](http://store.lhotka.net/Default.aspx?tabid=1560&ProductID=24) ebook.